# Django on IIS with Multiple Sites: How To Make ISAPI.py Cooperate

Tags: windows, django, iis-6

Python 2.6.2 / Django 1.0.2 on Win 2003 Standard IIS 6.

IIs is running two django sites with the following directory structure:

root/http/WEBSITE1
root/http/WEBSITE2

Both sites have their own application pools; each site has it's own pyISAPIe.dll instance.

WEBSITE1 is accessible (serving test django page). However, the browser produces the following for WEBSITE2:

Internal Server Error
An error occurred processing this request.

Request handler failed

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Http\Isapi.py", line 67, in Request
    return RunWSGI(Handler, Base=Base)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\Http\WSGI.py", line 155, in RunWSGI
    Result = Application(Environ, StartResponse)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 241, in **call**
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 122, in get_response
    return self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 166, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\views\defaults.py", line 23, in server_error
    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 81, in get_template
    source, origin = find_template_source(template_name)
  File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 74, in find_template_source
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist, name
django.template.TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html

It seems to me that "Isapi.py" located in root/pytho26/Lib/site-packages/Http has everything to do with this because of the "os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "WEBSITE1.settings"

How can I modify this file or position it so that both sites run independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, the solution lies here

http://groups.google.com/group/pyisapie/browse_thread/thread/b67e861c85e1b26a

Follow option #3 **to the letter** and you will be able to run multiple IIS sites.